# Relationship between test stat and p-value in relation to t-test

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, p-value

I was wondering  why it is necessarily true that if a test statistic exceeds the critical value of t, then it will also be true that the p-value will not exceed the level of significance.

Comment: What have you done to try to address the problem? What you're asking implies you don't know what *t*, *p*, or the test are. It's hard to tell exactly where you're confused. Please expand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this depends on what is meant by "exceed", but generally when people say a test statistics *exceeds* the critical value, they mean $|t|\boldsymbol{>}t_{\rm crit}$, and when they say the p-value *exceeds* the level of significance, they mean $p\boldsymbol{<}\alpha$.  Thus, when the test statistic exceeds the critical value of t, the p-value *also* exceeds the level of significance.

As to why that fact is the case, it is simply because the value of $t_{\rm crit}$ is *determined* by the point where $p<\alpha$.

Comment: +1 Good answer, though I'd add the minor point that in both cases, *equality* corresponds to rejection as well -- and while it's not an issue with continuously-distributed test statistics, it matters when they're discrete.